# Retrieve a query from Parse using NSArray

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to run a query to have the best 10 player with a high score in an array, I get nil when I run this query, what am I doing wrong ? please help

```
var userNames = NSArray!()
var genders = NSArray!()

let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
query.selectKeys(["topscoreuser", "username"])
query.orderByDescending("topscoreuser")
query.limit = 10
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
    if error == nil {
        userNames = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("username") as? NSArray
        genders =   PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("topscoreuser") as? NSArray
        print("\(userNames)")
        print("\(genders)")
    } else{
        //fail
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're doing a query to get some objects, and then ignoring them. You're also using the private User class name, which you shouldn't. You can use KVC to interrogate the `objects`:

```
var userNames = NSArray!()
var genders = NSArray!()

let query = PFUser.query()
query.selectKeys(["topscoreuser", "username"])
query.orderByDescending("topscoreuser")
query.limit = 10
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
    if error == nil {
        userNames = objects?.valueForKey("username") as? NSArray
        genders =   objects?.valueForKey("topscoreuser") as? NSArray
        print("\(userNames)")
        print("\(genders)")
    } else{
        //fail
    }
}
```